# Работа с файлами

Tags: php

Как из файла удалить определённый кусок текста (не по номеру строки)?

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. вопрос очень расплывчат, такой будет и ответ...

```
$file = file_get_contents('/url/'); //url - пусть к вашему файлу
$toReplace = 'это надо заменить';
$replace = ''; //пустота...

$file = str_replace($toReplace, $replace, $file);
// заменяем 'это надо заменить' на пустоту, т.е. удаляем
```

Появилиьс подозрения что ТС думает что обновив эту переменную мы обновляем содержимое файла...
Вообще на всякий случай вот:

```
// ложим уже измененную строку в этот же файл...
file_put_contents(/url/, $file); //url - путь к вашему файлу...
```

Comment: не заменить надо, а именно удалить

Comment: Ну замените $replace на ""<br>
учитесь думать...

Comment: не работает так, пробовал и не раз

Comment: Код в студию, плохо пробывали значит

Comment: $t = file_get_contents($file);
$r = '';
str_replace($toreplace, $r, $t);

Comment: ну понятно что $toreplace это строка которую меняем, прост не написал

Comment: Когда я писал чтобы вы код привели - вы должны были обновить свой вопрос, в нем написать свой код и ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНо содержимое txt файла, хотябы небольшой кусок с тем текстом который вы пытаетесь удалить, как в мане написано я вкурсе какбы...<br>
Обновил ответ, в который раз пытаюсь проявить екстрасенсорные способности...